# How involved would it be to build a Mac OS X usb driver for my Yamaha DGX-305 keyboard?

Tags: macos, midi, drivers

No drivers for Mac OS X exist for this keyboard, and I would like to use it to transmit midi data to my laptop in real time. I was able to do this with my previous Windows laptop and this keyboard. I've searched online and found [this list](http://download.yamaha.com/search/product/?site=usa.yamaha.com&language=en&category_id1=16277&category_id2=16084&category_id3=&product_id=105572) of drivers for it, which doesn't include Mac OS X. I have a background in programming but not in making drivers so I am not sure where I would even begin. Is this a feasible task or would I need to have access to some knowledge about the device itself that I probably don't have access to?

Comment: Most likely you've seen this, but it can be helpful : https://github.com/ysalathe/GenericUSBMIDI , at least something to start from.

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky actually no, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yamaha's USB MIDI devices are almost compatible with the [official USB MIDI specification](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/midi10.pdf); the only difference is in the descriptors.

You could either write your own driver, or start with [some existing driver](https://github.com/ysalathe/GenericUSBMIDI) that already speaks the protocol, and adjust it to use the correct interface/endpoint/port numbers for the DGX-305.

Comment: [Certain things](http://download.yamaha.com/search/detail/?site=usa.yamaha.com&language=en&category_id1=16277&category_id2=16084&product_id=105572&asset_file_language=EN&asset_id=31630) do not involve programming and thus would be off topic in the answer itself.